# returning back to the android app, from the browser, without restarting the app

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Phonegap to create an android application. The application has a feature that enables the user to visit a micro site by opening the android web browser. The micro site has a return button that will return the user back to the app.

I created my own scheme so I can launch the app from the android browser.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="microsite" />
</intent-filter>
```

My problem is that when the app is launch from the browser, the app is restarted.

How will I be able to return to the app without restarting the app? How to return to where I left off?

Comment: Use in `<activity>` tag this flag `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and inside the activity catch this by `@Override public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not a native android developer. I do know where to add 'android:launchMode="singleTop"' inside the <activity> tag but I don't know how to apply the catch inside the activity. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: when the call back using `microsite` occurs, the activity's `onNewIntent` function will be called.